# Preventing navigation in parent browser window while child window is open

Tags: javascript, browser

///this is a code to display a pop-up windows in javascript. how can prevent the user return to the parent window, until he close the pop-up window?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
  var stile = "top=10, left=10, width=600, height=800 status=no, menubar=no, toolbar=no scrollbar=no";
     function Popup(apri) {
        window.open(apri, "", stile);
     }
 //-->
</script>
<a href="javascript:Popup('YOURPAGE.html')">show popup</a>
```

Comment: You cannot do that with a mechanism based on a simple `window.open()` call.

Comment: Make your question a bit more descriptive.

Comment: Rather than using a new window, you should consider creating a [modal overlay](http://raventools.com/blog/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/)

Comment: Popups are to JS what Beverly Hills 90210 was to '90ies: a crappy famous thing we should forget of now.

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers that is NOT a popup window, it is a new tab opened in the browser. Check jquery or other javascript libraries to create a proper **modal** popup window. That is what you are looking for.

Check out http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

There are a gazillion such out-of-the-box solutions out there...

Answer (score 0):

The `window.open()` will open a new browser window or tab, neither of which will prevent the user from returning to the parent window.  This type of window is referred to as a [modal window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window), and is a common UI paradigm.

I'd suggest googling for `javascript modal` or `javascript overlay`, and you'll get lots of results explaining ways to do this.  It'll take a bit of work, but it's a good lesson in learning modern javascript techniques.

Depending on your needs, you may want to look into a javascript library to address this, or you could write the javascript and CSS manually.